# Eigenvector of real matrix corresponding to real eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is it true that for a given real matrix, $A$, the eigenvector corresponding to real eigenvalues of $A$ will have entirely real values?

I know that of course eigenvectors are the same up to a constant scaling factor, which could be a complex value. So I am asking if such eigenvectors can always be rescaled to totally real eigenvectors.

I can see the other way: given a real eigenvector of a real matrix, the corresponding eigenvalue must be real, but I'm having trouble with this direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Av=\lambda v$, where $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$, $\lambda\in \mathbb R$ and $v\in \mathbb C^n$. Observe, that $(A-\lambda I)\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$. By row manipulations, we can calculate $\operatorname{ker}(A-\lambda I)$, which is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$, because with every row manipulation there doesn't occur a complex but not real number. So, you are right, we get $v\in \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Thanks! Simple to follow. I was thinking up more complicated things but this is perfect

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that if $A \in M(n, \mathbb{C})$ has real entries and $Aw = \lambda w$ for some $w \in \mathbb{C}^n \setminus \{0\}$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, then there exists $u \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$ such that $Au = \lambda u$, i.e. we can find a real eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$.

To prove this, write $w = u + iv$ where $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^n$. We have $Aw = Au + iAv$ and $\lambda w = \lambda u + i \lambda v$. Thus $Au + iAv = \lambda u + i \lambda v$. Note that since $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, it follows that $\lambda u, \lambda v \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Thus equating real and imaginary parts gives $Au = \lambda u$, $Av = \lambda v$. Since $w \neq 0$, one of $u$ or $v$ is nonzero, say $u \neq 0$. Then $u$ is our desired real eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$.